# Hola comunidad. Estoy trabajando un bucle en R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, stata

Espero estén muy bien, tengo una pregunta relacionada con un bucle en R.
Mi u¿intención es poder general un bucle que me minimice el código.

Estoy generando unos objetos extraídos de una lista, pero quisiera poder minimizar estas lineas con un bucle de la manera que me tome estos números 1 hasta 12.

```
INGRESOS_1 = FILES_CONTE[[1]]

INGRESOS_2 = FILES_CONTE[[2]]

INGRESOS_3 = FILES_CONTE[[3]]

INGRESOS_4 = FILES_CONTE[[4]]

INGRESOS_5 = FILES_CONTE[[5]]

INGRESOS_6 = FILES_CONTE[[6]]

INGRESOS_7 = FILES_CONTE[[7]]

INGRESOS_8 = FILES_CONTE[[8]]

INGRESOS_9 = FILES_CONTE[[9]]

INGRESOS_10 = FILES_CONTE[[10]]

INGRESOS_11 = FILES_CONTE[[11]]

INGRESOS_12 = FILES_CONTE[[12]]
```

Comment: Bienvenido Nicolas  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

Con el paquete `apaTables` puedes crear y exportar diversas tablas en formato APA de manera sencilla. Para una regresión lineal tienes que usar la función `apa.reg.table` e ingresar el objeto lm. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
library(apaTables)
reg<- lm(formula= y ~ x1+x2, data= df)
apa.reg.table(reg, filename= "regresion.doc", table.number= 2)
```

Una gran ventaja de este paquete es que puedes exportar la tabla en formato .doc o .rtf. El argumento `table.number`, como podrás intuir, define el número de la tabla en tu documento. Te recomiendo que visites la [documentación](https://dstanley4.github.io/apaTables/articles/apaTables.html) del paquete para mas información.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias ! y en stata sabe que puedo utilizar ?

Comment: Desconozco si existe alguna forma de formatear tablas en stata, aunque intuyo que no es posible.